# Add class active to router link based on url in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have link something like this:

```
 <li class="list-item active"> <router-link :to="{name:'link-1'}"> Link 1</router-link>
 <li class="list-item"> <router-link :to="{name:'link-2'}"> Link 2</router-link>
```

I want to add class active with list-item class based on the url suppose if the url is localhost:8000/link-1 then link-1 should be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue router provides this functionality.  When a link is active, it will have the `router-link-exact-active` class applied.

In your CSS:

```css
.router-link-exact-active {
  // styles here
}
```

There is also `router-link-active` which would match both "/" and "/link-1".

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Vue Router > 3.1.0 you can use `<router-link>` and a scoped slot for this:

```html
<router-link
  :to="{name:'link-1'}"
  v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
>
  <li
    :class="[isActive && 'active', isExactActive && 'exact-active']"
  >
    <a :href="href" @click="navigate">Link 1</a>
  </li>
</router-link>

<router-link
  :to="{name:'link-2'}"
  v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
>
  <li
    :class="[isActive && 'active', isExactActive && 'exact-active']"
  >
    <a :href="href" @click="navigate">Link 2</a>
  </li>
</router-link>
```

If you don't need to have `.active` on the li elements, `<router-link>` has this build in. (See Dan's awnswer)